# Unfortunately application has stopped while running on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making first hello world app but its not running on my phone.
I have been searching solution for 2 days but nothing found, all it says is logcat error or exception error

Here in main activity

```
package com.example.wajheabidi.galary4;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here is log cat

```
10-13 12:34:54.380  27597-27597/com.example.wajheabidi.galary4 E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportHeight > 0
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:544)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:478)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:441)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:742)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:362)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:720)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at com.example.wajheabidi.galary4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5304)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is stack trace

```
  // IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
  // Implementation of methods is not available

package android.os;

public final class Looper {
    Looper() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static void prepare() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static void prepareMainLooper() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static android.os.Looper getMainLooper() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static void loop() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static android.os.Looper myLooper() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static android.os.MessageQueue myQueue() { /* compiled code */ }

    public boolean isCurrentThread() { /* compiled code */ }

    public void setMessageLogging(android.util.Printer printer) { /* compiled code */ }

    public void quit() { /* compiled code */ }

    public void quitSafely() { /* compiled code */ }

    public java.lang.Thread getThread() { /* compiled code */ }

    public android.os.MessageQueue getQueue() { /* compiled code */ }

    public void dump(android.util.Printer pw, java.lang.String prefix) { /* compiled code */ }

    public java.lang.String toString() { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

Comment: post android monitor --logcat  output please!

Comment: post your logcat error here

Comment: 1) if you want some help, post the error. 2) DON'T ask for problems that can be solved by debugging... look some tutorials and learn how to work with android

Comment: `Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportHeight > 0` post your full xml. and what is line 17 in that? it looks like you are missing `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` somewhere.

Comment: i update my question know you can see
actually i have android 1.1.0 then i update it to 2.2.1
but it slow my laptop so i delete it and again install android 1.1.0
it will run my old apps but not run my new apps which i make

Comment: its my full xml and simple hello world program which is automatic generated my android studio

Comment: whenever i make new project and run in my phone it show same error
"stop unfortunately, app has stopped"